# REST Task not visible in jBPM 6 palette in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rest, jboss, jbpm

I am trying to implement a simple REST service call in JBPM 6 and somehow I can't see the REST Task in the palette whereas in the documentation it is mentioned and also it is there in KIEWorkbench.

I am not sure if there is some specific configuration required to have the REST Task in the palette.

Any sort of information would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of documentation do you follow in order to do it ? I've followed this part of official documentation and works fine for me:

http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.4.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch21.html#d0e27951